# Usage of the phrase "go get 'em, tiger"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

I am writing a card to a (female) colleague who is leaving for another position. Is it inappropriate to use the phrase "go get 'em, tiger"? Does this phrase have any bad "connotation"?

Comment: There's nothing _'bad'_ about that phrase. But you should avoid using it if the card is a formal one. If it's going to be an informal _'Good luck !'_ card, then there's no harm.

Comment: consider tigress. Only if you people are friends. It gives the phrase customization, wittiness and a personal touch.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's sexist, but it might be seen as patronizing. I'd probably pick a more original sentiment if you can come up with one. It is a phrase very few people use unironically. Especially in business communication it never hurts to be as clear as possible. Leave no room for misunderstanding. Even if they're not offended, it might be seen as weird.

Something like

> Good luck with your new job/future endeavors

Is bloodless, but you will be absolutely not run into trouble using it.